# Strange behavior with linuxfb or eglfs -platform option

Tags: arm, cross-platform, qt5

I write a simple program,[ you can download at 149.154.154.92/focus.zip ] with qt5.1 and qtcreator.
It is very simple, mainwindow and 1 qdialog. 
I exec the dialog with a button and I close it with an other button.
If I run the program on x86 platform all is ok.

If I run the program on arm embedded system with the eglfs platform option I can exec the dialog but when I try to close it, the application is locked, and the dialog it is not hided.

If I run the program on arm embedded system with the linuxfb platform option I can exec the dialog but when I close it, the mainwindow is not repainted but it can capture the input and I can exec the dialog again.

What I wrong?
Thank you

Comment: I noticed the same weird behavior here: when closing applications launched with `-platform eglfs` the screen is not cleared out (I am running Qt 5.2.1 on TI AM335x board here). I see that your post is quite old... Did you find a solution about that meanwhile?